# how to use social sharing plugin in browser(pwa) in ionic 4?

Tags: ionic-framework, progressive-web-apps

how to use social sharing plugin in browser(pwa) in ionic 4 ?
in [social sharing document](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/social-sharing) browser is platform supported.
but when use in browser throw warning:

```
 Native: tried calling SocialSharing.share, but Cordova is not available. Make sure to include cordova.js or run in a device/simulator
```

Comment: I am also facing the same issue. Did you resolve that?

Comment: reply Suraj Khanal,No

Comment: Have you tried this with capacitor? or cordova platform browser?

Answer (score -1):

If your aim is to support social sharing, It's now possible to access the native share data of a mobile phone

```
            async function share(title, text, url) {
              if (window.Windows) {
                const DataTransferManager = window.Windows.ApplicationModel.DataTransfer.DataTransferManager;

                const dataTransferManager = DataTransferManager.getForCurrentView();
                dataTransferManager.addEventListener("datarequested", (ev) => {
                  const data = ev.request.data;

                  data.properties.title = title;
                  data.properties.url = url;
                  data.setText(text);
                });

                DataTransferManager.showShareUI();

                return true;
              } else if (navigator.share) {
                try {
                  await navigator.share({
                    title: title,
                    text: text,
                    url: url,
                  });

                  return true;
                } catch (err) {
                  console.error('There was an error trying to share this content');
                  return false;
                }
              }
            }
```

You can read more [Here](https://www.pwabuilder.com/feature/Create%20Share)